# alternative to dlply in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

My dataframe contains the following:

```
data$Value   data$Name
774          Name1
770          Name1
778          Name1
804          Name1
804          Name1
802          Name1
804          Name1
900          Name2
905          Name2
805          Name2
900          Name2
950          Name2
860          Name2
870          Name2
etc...       etc... for 100 Names
```

So, each Name has 7 Values associated to it. I would like to group this data frame by variable "Name", split it and returning the 7 values for each of those names as a list. This is the format of my desired output:

```
my_list$Name1 = 
[[1]]
[1] 774 770 778 804 804 802 804 

my_list$Name2 = 
[[1]]
[1] 900, 905, 805, 900, 950, 860, 870  

etc...
```

The easiest solution is to use plyr's `dlply` function:

```
my_list <- dlply(data, "Name", function(x) list(x$Value))
```

However, I would like to avoid using plyr. What would be a good alternative? I have considered splitting my data the following way:

```
splits <- function(x) { 
  y <- subset(data, select = c(Name, Value))
  splits <- split(y, y$Name)
  return(splits)
}

my_list <- splits(data)
```

However, this still returns me a list in the following format:

```
      Value   Name
      (dbl)   (chr)
1      774    Name1
2      770    Name1
3      778    Name1
4      804    Name1
5      804    Name1
6      802    Name1
7      804    Name1
```

UPDATE: SOLUTION:

```
my_list <- lapply(split(data$Value, data$Name), list)
```

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(split(dd$Value, dd$Name), list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it,

```
y <- subset(data, select = c(Name, Value))
list <- split(y, y$Name)

unlist(sapply(list, '[', 1))
```

or

```
unlist(unname(sapply(list, '[', 1)))
```

or simply (compliments of @docendo discimus)

```
unlist(unname(split(y$Value, y$Name)))
```

Regarding your comment, then you can do,

```
unname(split(y$Value, y$Name))
#[[1]]
#[1] 774 770 778 804 804 802 804

#[[2]]
#[1] 900 905 805 900 950 860 870
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do somthing like `split(y$Value, y$Name)`?

Comment: Yes, I guess `unlist(unname(split(y$Value, y$Name)))` would work.

Comment: @Sotos: your first solution returns me an error: "Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?".