# Alternative to dlply in R or dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I'm trying to remove dependency on plyr and have a line which uses the `dlply` function.

```
translation <- dlply(data ,.(key), function(s) key = as.list(s))
```

I've tried to use `lapply` and `split` based on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964987/alternative-to-dlply-in-r) but cannot work out how to translate the key and as.list parts.

Comment: Perhaps you need `split(data, data$key)`

Comment: Can you give a [mcve]  please ? (i.e., some sample data, to save us the trouble of making it up for ourselves)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to get similar structure, use `split` and then `unclass`

```
lapply(split(data, data$key), unclass)
```

-testing

```
lapply(split(head(mtcars), head(mtcars)$cyl), unclass)
```

Comment: This seemed to do it, thank you! I'll test then accept the answer